# Add scrollbar in Material Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this Material Grid into which I have many items.

```
        <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="flex-start" alignItems="flex-start">
            <Grid item xs={5}>
                <Box m={5} pl={10}>
                    test 2
                </Box>

                <Box m="4rem" />

            </Grid>
            ................
        </Grid>
```

I'm interested how I can add horizontal scrollbar to scroll the Grid items?

Comment: Do you mean instead of vertically load items, you would like to load items horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your components to use GridList and GridListTile if this is what you are looking for: https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#single-line-grid-list